# Writing commands to BungeeCord Process OutputStream does not appear to execute them

Tags: bungeecord

Here is the code I am using to read / write to a BungeeCord process. Only issue is it appears that writing commands to the output stream does not appear to work.

http://pastebin.com/JvsetSUq

I believe my code is working correctly for the following reasons:

- I have checked that that the code that writes to the output stream is being reached with the correct command
- This code works flawlessly using the Spigot server jar.

Comment: please add code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by disabling JLine in command arguments.